# Get result of EXEC sp_helptext with EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Are there any way to get the results of this c# command (using Entity Framework 6):

```
var result = _model.Database.SqlQuery<???>("EXEC sp_helptext dbo.AProcedure", new object());
```

I have tried to substitute ??? by string in this way:

```
var result = _model.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC sp_helptext dbo.AProcedure", new object());
```

But only get the sql executed text: `EXEC sp_helptext dbo.AProcedure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with this method to get procedure content.

```
private string GetProcedureBody(string procedureName)
{
    var data = _model.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec sp_helptext @name", 
                    new SqlParameter("name", procedureName));
    var procedureLines = data.ToList();
    return string.Join("", procedureLines.ToArray());
}
```

Thanks to @James Dev for his help and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok because you are trying to execute a system stored procedure this cannot easily be done from Entity Framework so use DbCommand. Try this

```
        var entityConnection = MyDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        DbConnection conn = entityConnection;
        ConnectionState initialState = conn.State;

        if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Open();
        using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_helptext";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", "dbo.AProcedure"));
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

Comment: Procedure body as in the SQL code and not the result?

Comment: The result of `EXEC sp_helptext procedurename` is the procedure body.  I would like to get the procedure body lines.

Comment: result variable only contains the sql text sent/executed.  With model (edmx) or dbcontext is the same.

Comment: Ok because you are trying to execute a system stored procedure this cannot easily be done from Entity Framework so use DbCommand updated answer